# Expected value of the F-Distribution dependent on the degrees of freedom associated with the Chi-square random variable in the denominator?

Tags: distributions, expected-value, chi-squared-distribution, f-distribution

0

The F-Distribution has a Probability Density Function that can be defined as:

[image: F-Distribution PDF]

with an expected value of:

[image: F-Distribution Expected Value]

What would be a logical explanation for why the expected value only depends on the degrees of freedom associated with the Chi-square random variable in the denominator, and not from the numerator (I .e., depends on 'm' and not on both 'm' and 'n')?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

if $X\sim \Gamma (a,\lambda)$ so $E(X^{k})=\frac{\Gamma(a+k)}{\Gamma(a)}\lambda^k$

so  $X\sim \chi^{(2)}_{(n)}=\Gamma (\frac{n}{2},2)$ so $E(X^{k})=\frac{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2}+k)}{\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})}2^k$

$$F_{(n-1,m-1)}=\frac{\frac{\chi^{(2)}_{(n-1)}}{n-1}}{\frac{\chi^{(2)}_{(m-1)}}{m-1}}$$

$$E(F_{(n-1,m-1)})=E\left( \frac{\frac{\chi^{(2)}_{(n-1)}}{n-1}}{\frac{\chi^{(2)}_{(m-1)}}{m-1}} \right)=E\left(
\frac{\chi^{(2)}_{(n-1)}}{n-1} 
\right)E\left( \frac{1}{\frac{\chi^{(2)}_{(m-1)}}{m-1}} \right)$$

note that 
$$E\left(
\frac{\chi^{(2)}_{(n-1)}}{n-1} 
\right)=1$$

so

$$E(F_{(n-1,m-1)})=E\left( \frac{1}{\frac{\chi^{(2)}_{(m-1)}}{m-1}} \right)
=(m-1)E\left\{\left( \chi^{(2)}_{(m-1)}\right)^{-1}\right\}$$

Comment: This is just what I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: You are welcome